# What is the chance of having a villager selling 3 mending books at once?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I got 3 mending books on 1 villager. I don't really know the chances, so can somebody explain?

Comment: Explain or calculate the chances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the wiki on trading with a librarian](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Trading#Librarian):

> The enchantment is chosen randomly with equal chance of any enchantment type occurring (except for Soul Speed and Swift Sneak) and equal chance to get any level of the enchantment

Also according to this wiki page, two trades are randomly chosen per level, which means that a Librarian has a 2/3 chance of getting a book trade as a Novice, Apprentice, and Journeyman and a 2/4 chance as an Expert.

Looking at the [list of enchantments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting) we can see there are currently 39 enchantments in the game, minus soul speed and swift sneak, so 37 relevant ones.

If I interpret the wiki correctly in that it first chooses an enchantment, then the level (which is irrelevant for Mending) this would mean that we don't need to bother about all the different levels decreasing our chance of getting a mending book.

That means that here are the chances of getting one Mending (or any other specific enchantment for that matter) book from the same villager:

| level | calculation | chance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| novice | `1 / 37 x 2 / 3` | `2 / 111` or `1.8%` |
| apprentice | `1 / 37 x 2 / 3` | `2 / 111` or `1.8%` |
| journeyman | `1 / 37 x 2 / 3` | `2 / 111` or `1.8%` |
| expert | `1 / 37 x 2 / 4` | `2 / 148` or `1.2%` |

Now, to get any X amount of books with the same enchantment from the same librarian, we need to look at the various combinations of chances.

| amount | calculation | chance | rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `N+A+J+E` | `5/74` or `6.7%` | ~1 in 15 |
| 2 | `N*A + N*J + N*E + A*J + A*E + J*E` | `7/4107` or `0.17%` | ~1 in 600 |
| 3 | `N*A*J + N*A*E + N*J*E + A*J*E` | `26/1367631` or `0.0019%` | ~1 in 52k |
| 4 | `N*A*J*E` | `4/50602347` or `0.0000079%` | ~1 in 12.6M |

Comment: Okay, thank you